# switching from MeshBasicMaterial to MeshStandardMaterial just shows black screen

Tags: three.js

Three.js question here. Not sure why my code isn't working when I make the call to MeshStandardMaterial on line 10. It works when I switch it to MeshBasicMaterial, but I need the functionality of MeshStandardMaterial in order to add a .bumpMap to my render. Can anyone help with this?

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5,32,32);
// const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'textures/8081_earthmap10k.jpg' );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );




const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 15;

const animate = function () {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    // cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

};

animate();
```

The code above works correctly and shows a spinning white(0xffffff) sphere on a black background, but the code below does not work, it just shows a black background..

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5,32,32);
// const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'textures/8081_earthmap10k.jpg' );
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );




const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 15;

const animate = function () {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    // cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

};

animate();
```

Again, the only thing I'm changing on both is the call to MeshStandardMaterial on line 10... Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MeshBasicMaterial` is an unlit material. `MeshStandardMaterial` is a lit material instead.

So as long as you don't add lights to your scene or an environment map to the material, objects with  `MeshStandardMaterial` will be black.

Comment: Ohh thanks! So would it be adding a .lightMap attribute or .lightMapIntensity to the MeshStandardMaterial to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

NVM, i got it. I just added

```
const color = 0xFFFFFF;
const intensity = 1;
const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(color, intensity);
scene.add(light);
```

after adding my sphere and it worked!
cheers!!

thanks to user Mugen87 for clarifying this!

Answer (score 0):

I had a BufferGeometry and the **Vertices had no normal vectors**.
As soon as I added the 'normal' attribute, the object was colored.

```
geometry.setAttribute("normal", new Float32BufferAttribute( normals, 3 ) );
```